# Loop a Follow Path Animation?

Tags: animation, modifiers

I've been trying to apply a Cycles modifier to my follow path animation. It's fully selected, and I've set all of the proper values in the Cycles modifier, but it doesn't work. If you know how to fix this, that'd be great. Thank you! :)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please show a well chosen screen capture of your work.  It may speed up any help you receive.  The choice is yours.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger I added a screenshot. The modifier is on the right. It's used to loop animations a certain/infinite amounts of times, however it isn't working for my follow path animation.

Comment: Are you sure you have two keyframes of different values? You could just delete all keyframes and insert the keyframes for a quick fix ... hopefully

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger Yup, I tried that.

Comment: Please show your work as a screen capture with the suggestion.  Lets see the work of 3 or more different values for the offset.  Lets see what happens with values of 1 and .5 and .75 and 0.   Do you feel you have inserted keyframes many time?

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger I can't seem to record Blender for some reason, so I'll just explain it as best as I can.

I have a sphere which is moving along a path using the follow path modifier. Then, I have the offset key framed at 1 and 100. With these frames selected, I added a cycles modifier in the graph editor. However, once I press play, the animation only goes once. I've tried many different values, re-inserting the key frames about 5 times, and changing the offset.

Comment: Oh, kk. I'll grab some screenshots rq.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118564/discussion-between-mmmchezburgerz-and-atomicbezierslinger).

Comment: Screen captures are fine. I need no recording. This is a small problem. Please show your Follow Path modifier. I use it one particular way. Hopefully the [modern ] way.  My understanding is the whole curve is repeated not just the current selection of graph points.  The very first large image you have above is not useful because it show the same values on casual inspection.  This casts doubt on the whole question. Please show different values on different keyframes.  Deleting all your keyframes and getting a fresh start is suggested.  The choice is yours.  Your new little images help.

Comment: I also use/select the fixed position on the Follow Path Constraint.  The check box.  There are also tutorials perhaps here on BSE and certainly on the famous website which has a name that rhymes with noonoob.

Answer (score -1):

Use visibly different values to more clearly see a cycles modifier effect.
Try some example values such as all four values [0,.5,0,.75] at different frames.

Comment: I've tried that, it doesn't seem to work either. :\